# Can't run Jekyll with pygments

Tags: ruby, jekyll, pygments

I'm trying to run jekyll on my OS X, but get the error:

```
Configuration file: /Users/antonshuvalov/Desktop/largescalejs/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/antonshuvalov/Desktop/largescalejs
       Destination: /Users/antonshuvalov/Desktop/largescalejs/_site
      Generating... /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.8/lib/posix/spawn.rb:187: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.
```

But if I push this blog on github, everything works fine

Comment: But if I push this blog on github, everything works fine

Comment: Just a side note: You should edit your question instead of commenting when you want to provide additional info. Comments are easily skipped by readers when skimming through questions.

Comment: Make sure you have the newest version of Jekyll installed. It seems like there was a related bug a while ago: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/667

Comment: @p11y, thanks. I updated Jekyll from 1.3.2 to 1.4.2 but it's not work too. =(

Comment: Oh oh, so strange. If I run jekyll by `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` I get error, but if I run jekyll directly (`jekyll serve --watch`) all works perfect.